# Feature request: Add search radius to the Suggestion Complete Venues api method

Tags: foursquare

I'm integrating the suggestion complete venues search into my site.  It's pulling back results from places that are way to far away from the city we want to search in.  Can you add a search radius param to the api method?

Comment: That would be really helpful. Until then, you could filter out results with a too high `distance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radius parameter is in fact available, though documentation for this parameter was missing. Thanks for pointing this out, documentation will be added.

Comment: thanks for updating the docs.  i'm glad this feature is already in and I don't have to wait!

Comment: the radius parameter doesn't seem to do anything.  if i set the radius to 5, i still get results back that are about 10 miles (8000 meters) away.  am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That's very strange, I'm trying out the radius parameter and it seems to work for me. Are you setting the ll parameter in the request properly, and still finding venues that are very far from the ll provided?

Comment: I tried intent=browse and radius=500, but still receive (some) results with distance around 6000. I used the java API (https://github.com/wallabyfinancial/foursquare-api-java). Any idea what might be wrong?